# Ruby for webpage data extraction to excel

Tags: ruby

Can Ruby usefull to extract data from webpage to excel? like Select list,radio button values.reading HTML table data etc

Thanks,
Arup

Comment: If `roo` cannot satisfy your need, try `axlsx`.

Comment: Before looking at roo or axlsx or spreadsheet, make sure the much simpler CSV doesn't already do what you need.

Comment: I want only to design a script that will navigate to the third party webpage and gather the information from there to my spreadsheet.That is the whole purpose- clicking on the lables,collect different field values etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. Try nokogiri (http://nokogiri.org/) and Roo (https://github.com/Empact/roo).

Comment: I am totally fresh to Ruby. So can you tell me how and what i need to install in my desktop to achieve such code designing? Thanks as always.

Comment: If you're on Windows, start here: http://rubyinstaller.org/.  If you're on Linux/Mac, start here: https://rvm.io/ or here: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.  Specific questions should go in a new post.